# printing array in a reverse order, unexpected outputs (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, cin, cout

I am new to programming, my starting language is c++ right now. I'm having trouble printing some arrays in a reverse order.
After looping and incrementing a the variable each incrementing inputs a value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

   int x=0;
   int a=0;
   int y=0;
   int arrayOne[40];
   int numberofTimes;
   int decrement;
   int operatorx;


cout<<"Enter first number: ";
cin>>numberofTimes;

for(int x; x<numberofTimes;x++){
    cout<<"Enter second number: ";
    cin>>y;
    arrayOne[x]=y;}
    decrement=numberofTimes*2;
while(decrement>numberofTimes){
    cout<<arrayOne[x]<<endl;
    x=x-1;
    decrement=decrement-1;
    }
   return 0;}
```

Comment: I think it's time you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code you show. There's very little in it that makes sense.

Comment: What is your input? What does your program output? What do you expect?

Comment: `int x` in for loop is used without initializing, undefined behavior alert!!

Comment: One of the very first things you need to learn about C++ is that you must turn on all of your compiler's warning messages, and ***do not ignore them***. Your C++ compiler already figured out several bugs in your code, and it's telling you about them. Don't ignore warning messages from your C++ compiler. Your C++ compiler is your friend, and it wants you to write correct code. Every C++ program you write should produce exactly zero warning messages from your compiler. If it doesn't, figure out why, and fix it.

Comment: You should avoid C-style arrays and read https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-stack and https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rsl-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code has only two real errors (but lots of 'dodgy' stuff)! The following is a corrected/annotated, working version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;// = 0; // It is better to initialize this at the start of the FOR loop!
//  int a = 0; // You never use this variable!
    int y = 0;
    int arrayOne[40];
    int numberofTimes;
//  int decrement; // Better to declare and initialize this in one go (below)
//  int operatorx; // This is never used!
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> numberofTimes;
//  for (int x; x < numberofTimes; x++) { // Here, you create a new variable, 'x' that hides the one you
    for (x = 0; x < numberofTimes; x++) { // have already defined; instead, use this to initialise x to zero
        cout << "Enter second number: ";
        cin >> y;
        arrayOne[x] = y;
    }
    int decrement = numberofTimes * 2; // Declare and initialise when needed!
    while (decrement > numberofTimes) {
        x = x - 1; // At the end of the first (FOR) loop, x will point to BEYOND the end of the array ...
        cout << arrayOne[x] << endl; // ... so you need to decrement it BEFORE accessing the elements!
    //  x = x - 1;
        decrement = decrement - 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further explanations!

Comment: Why would you suggest to not initialize a variable, e.g. `y`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Because the value it is initialized to is never used! First occurrence is on input: `cin >> y;`

Comment: That's no reason to not initialize it. It's a possible source of error if you change code. Your variables should always be initialized.

Comment: @ThomasSablik OK, in the case of `y` the `cin >> y` could fail - so I've edited my answer in your favour!

Comment: the final value of x in the for loop would be 3 am I right? then the  part which is x=x-1 would be x=3-1 which is 2, then the starting printing of my array would be arrayOne[2]?? which is not the case in the output base on my understanding

Comment: @turquoisecj Assuming a value of `3` for `numberofTimes`, then, yes, `x` will be three after the `for` loop finishes. But, for three numbers, the array elements you want to print will be `arrayOne[0]`, `arrayOne[1]` and `arrayOne[2]` (only in the other order). Remember: array indexes start at ***zero*** in C++!!